# I'm confused about what must I do (android rendering engine)

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering-engine

I'm developing an Android application with OpenGL.

I'm very new with Android and OpenGL and my English is very poor. Yesterday I earned -4 points because I didn't explain something correctly.

I will try to explain my problem:

I have to show more than one 3D object on screen, for example a cube and a sphere. The objects that I'm going to use will be more complex.

Now, I can show one 2D object perfectly following this [tutorial](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/04/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-ii-building-a-polygon/), but I don't know how to show a 3D object and neither more than one.

I use Blender to model 3D objects. I want to use these models with my application.

I have found a Java loader from Wavefront OBJ format [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/ModelLoader.java?r=250). Now I can export my models to that format and then import it to my Android application.

Someone told me something about using a rendering engine. But I don't know what is a rendering engine.

But I have some restrictions:

I'm also using a native C++ SDK that uses OpenGL. If I'm going to use a Java rendering engine I will need to pass the data (visible targets, projection and pose matrices, etc.) from native to Java. For this I will use the JNI (Java Native Interface).

Another thing to consider with this native C++ SDK if it needs to create the OpenGL context with specific parameters, depending on the device. You'll need to make sure that my rendering engine allows an outside source to set up the GL context, or pass the appropriate settings to the engine myself.

In other words, I'm lose.

If you need more details, tell me.

My question is, if I use blender to model some objects, how can I show these objects on Android? May I need a rendering engine? a Java or a C++ rendering engine?

If you know books, tutorials or examples, please tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/). It has loaders for common 3D formats (MD5, OBJ) and allows cross-platform development